# SQLboiler not in clause

Tags: sql, go, orm, sqlboiler

I am trying to follow the examples in sqlboiler (https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler). But, I can't find a way to get equivalent of `NOT IN` query.

```
users, err := models.Users(
  Select("id", "name"),
  Where("age > ?", 30),
  AndIn("c.kind in ?", "visa", "mastercard"),
).All(ctx, db)
```

In this example, if, we could get an operation `AndNotIn`, it'd be great.

Thanks!

Comment: If your question has been answered, it would be good to accept that answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm seeing `AndNotIn` in current versions of SQLBoiler generated code.

Looks like it was added on [July 3rd, 2020](https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/blob/d551047361e2a3580169ce51d6445db17ae0d073/CHANGELOG.md#v420---2020-07-03).

Answer (score 0):

use `qm.WhereIn("c.kind not in ?", "visa", "mastercard")`

or in a more universal format `qm.WhereIn("someColumeName not in ?", values...)`

notice that `values` should be already converted to `[]interface{}`

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
users, err := models.Users(qm.Select("id","name"),qm.Where("age > ?",30),model.UsersWhere.Kind.NIN([]string{"visa","mastercard"})).All(context.Background(),db)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error is -- ",err)
}
resp, _ := json.Marshal(users)
fmt.Println("result ",bytes.NewBuffer(resp))
```

where imported package qm is  -

> "github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/v4/queries/qm"